# How to set the n smallest values of a 1D DataFrame to a specific value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've a 1D DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    data=[[2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0]],
)
```

means

```
  A   B   C   D
0 2.0 3.0 0.0 1.0
```

. I'd like to set the `n` smallest values to `0.0`. E.g. with `n = 3` I'd like to have

```
  A   B   C   D
0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0
```

. What's the most efficient implementation for my problem w.r.t. execution time and memory consumption?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a DataFrame with a single row instead of just a Series?

Comment: @Rob Yes, there is a reason to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `nsmallest` is expecting a `columns` argument, you could transpose, and the use `nsmallest` to index the dataframe with the resulting indices:

```
df[df.T.squeeze().nsmallest(3).index] = 0.
```

---

```
print(df)

   A    B    C    D
0  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [numpy.argpartition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    data=[[2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0]],
)

n = 3
indices = np.argpartition(df.squeeze(), n)[:n]
df.iloc[0, indices] = 0

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     A    B    C    D
0  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0
```

The function argpartition uses [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect) as the selection algorithm. It has a `O(n)` worst case performance. From Wikipedia:

> is a selection algorithm that is a hybrid of quickselect and median of
>   medians which has fast average performance and optimal worst-case
>   performance

Comment: `Wall time: 11 ms` on my machine.

Comment: Does this implementation scale better than the above one accepted right now?

Comment: I cannot tell, could not found info on what algorithm is nsmallest using